# How to check what a gradle task does in building android project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Often I want to know what a gradle task is doing in building an android project. Not only its inputs and outputs but also how it gets the outputs from inputs. For example at the moment I want to know how the task `transformClassesWithDexBuilderForRelease` performs its work. I can know its inputs and outputs by printing `transformClassesWithDexBuilderForRelease.getInputs()` and `transformClassesWithDexBuilderForRelease.getOutputs()` in build.gradle. I guess it is using a dex tool like `d8` to build a dex file. I want to know whether I'm correct and want to know how the task is using the tool, like what options it is using. So how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with the command line, check out this [link](https://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/233-how-to-build-apk-file-from-command-line). There given steps of compilation android app

Comment: Thanks. But I want to know how the gradle tasks doing these work.